# Object appears in camera?

Tags: python, game-engine, camera, logic-bricks

How can I investigate if an object appears through a camera in BGE?

Ray sensor does not suit me cause it is one line, while I am searching for the whole screen.

Comment: [My answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39010/2217) should help you.

Comment: @David I think it is your answer that will help me but I 've failed to make it work so far, even with simple examples. The object to which I placed the radar sensor is a camera, where I used its local axis to define the radar axis and also I 've tried different angles. None of which seemed to work. To be more clear since it printed none of the messages it seemed that it never got the sensor to get activated. Do you have a blend to share?

Comment: Nevermind, used physics visualization and it seemed I had the distance wrong. Many thanks. Make it dupli to divert people to the answer. Or post a new one to mark it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the API does not provide direct access to the frustum calculation.

You can use [KX_Camera.boxInsideFrustum](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bge.types.KX_Camera.html#bge.types.KX_Camera.boxInsideFrustum), [KX_Camera.sphereInsideFrustum](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bge.types.KX_Camera.html#bge.types.KX_Camera.sphereInsideFrustum) and [bge.types.KX_Camera.pointInsideFrustum](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bge.types.KX_Camera.html#bge.types.KX_Camera.pointInsideFrustum) to get an estimate if something is at the screen (or maybe not).